# При наведении плавно увеличить высоту блока

Tags: jquery

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как в `jQuery` при наведении на блок - плавно увеличить его высоту на заданное кол-во пикселей, и при отпуске - плавно уменьшить до исходных размеров.

Comment: Используйте методы [.hover()][1] или [.mouseenter()][2]/[.mouseleave()][3] и [.animate()][4]

   [1]:http://api.jquery.com/hover/
   [2]:http://api.jquery.com/mouseenter/
   [3]:http://api.jquery.com/mouseleave/
   [4]:http://api.jquery.com/animate/

Answer (score 4):

```
var speed=1000,
    originalHeight=200,
    hoverHeight=500;

$('#ID-нужного-блока').hover(function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height:hoverHeight},speed);
},function(){
    $(this).stop().animate({height:originalHeight},speed);
})
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/c2MDe/).

Comment: Спасибо. А если оригинальная высота неизвестна или всегда разная?

Comment: При наведении, до выполнения действий получите параметры высоты. На примере @Crasher :

    var speed=1000,
        originalHeight=0,
        hoverHeight=500;

    $('#ID-нужного-блока').hover(function(){
        originalHeight = $(this).height();
    // и т.д. ...

Comment: @Deonis нельзя так, там же stop() анимации...

Answer (score 3):

Открываем документацию и читаем:

1. http://api.jquery.com/hover/
2. http://api.jquery.com/category/events/event-object/
3. http://api.jquery.com/animate/

В итоге получаем: http://jsfiddle.net/mWyAg/

Answer (score 1):

Недавно сам делал такую штуку. Нужно было ограничить текст по высоте, раскрывать этот текст и скрывать. [Вот тут мой пример:](http://jsfiddle.net/8UeN3/) http://jsfiddle.net/8UeN3/

Определяем высоту вложенных объектов:

```
function getTotalHeigh(obj)
{
    var totalHeight = 0;
    obj.children().each(function () {
        totalHeight += $(this).height();
    });
    return totalHeight;
}
```

При наведении, плавно увеличивать:

```
    $(this)
    .css({'border-bottom': '1px #223322 dotted'})
    .mouseover(function(){
        var tH = getTotalHeigh($(this));
        $(this).animate({
            'height': tH,
            'borderBottomWidth': '0px'
        }, 1000);
    })
```